# Return specific markup in helper when building atom_feed in Nanoc

Tags: erb, nanoc

In my Nanoc based blog I have a helper that builds a bunch of html which only makes sense in the web version of the article.
I'd like to emit different markup when the article is compiled via the atom_feed helper in order to render something that works in a feed reader. How would I best go about that? Is there a way to tell what target is being rendered?

I've tried just using the normal helper and the result is that I have artifacts in my feed.
The browser version looks like [image: this] and the feed reader like [image: this].